# MongoDB - Use $where inside $elemMatch

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's say I have a collection with accounts that each account has array of users:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  users: [
    {
      firstName: a,
      lastName: b
    },
    {
      firstName: c,
      lastName: c
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to query all accounts where at least one user has the same `firstName` and `lastName`

I tried to do something like this:

```
db.accounts.find({users: {
    $elemMatch: {
        $where: "this.firstName == this.lastName"
    }
}})
```

But of course it didn't work because of this error:

> Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $elemMatch cannot contain $where expression

I want to use the `find` and not `aggregate`.
Is there some other way to do it?

Comment: Why don't you want to use aggregation?

Comment: @chridam Not all users has permissions for aggregation queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try to use `$where` with [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) as below.

```
> db.collection.find({
             $where: function() {
                  return this.users.some(function(obj){ 
                           return obj.firstName == obj.lastName;
                 })
            }})
```

Answer (score 2):

Bit out of the box, but since `$where` relies on JavaScript evaluation, then this aggregate with [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) should actually run a lot faster since it uses native operators:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": {
                "$anyElementTrue": {
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$users",
                        "as": "user",
                        "in": { "$eq": [ "$$user.firstName", "$$user.lastName" ] }
                    }
                }
            },
            "then": "$$KEEP",
            "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }}
])
```

So the [`$anyElementTrue`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/) combined with [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) basically works the same as JavaScript `.some()` here, in that if any of the elements actually had the same `"firstName"` as `"lastName"`, then this is a `true` match and the document is "kept". Otherwise it is "pruned" and discarded.

So with the native operator speed, I would go with that over `$where` evaulation. I know you say you don't want to, but you possibly did not consider the statement was this simple or this much faster than the alternative either.

Comment: nice answer. I still need the `find` answer, but I learned a lot from this.

Comment: You should have used `$cond` between the `$redact` and the `if`

Comment: @Tom Thanks. Happens to me most days, as I just start writing in the conditions. I actually quite wish the syntax would change to just be like that and not use `$cond`, since it is indeed the only argument. I wrote it in after an appropriate `$where` was already given because I feel that you misunderstand something if you think you still use to use `.find()`. You are gaining no advantage, and are in fact choosing the less performant option. Those are facts. Perhaps you need to combine with other query conditions and you just dont't know how? Whatever it is, you should reconsider.

Comment: For myself of course your answer in better. I need it just for users who are allowed to use only `find()` queries - permissions issues. that's the reason

Comment: @Tom "permissions?" I know of no such thing. Can you point me to which actions restrict the use of aggregate? This is the [actions list](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#security-user-actions). I think someone is telling you "porkies", as to my knowledge anything with [find](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#authr.find) can also execute aggregate. They are just meant to be CRUD permissions.

Comment: I know it can't be restricted via mongo, these are restrictions within our small company, not all users are allowed to use aggregate (several reasons for that)

Comment: @Tom Wow! Sounds like someones boss needs to be educated. That's the attitude of someone with absolutely no idea what they are talking about. Please pass that on.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#behavior) is quite clear about it:

> You cannot specify a $where expression as a query criterion for $elemMatch.

What you can do, is iterate the array within `$where`:

```
db.collection.find(function(){
    for(var i in this.users) {
        if(this.users[i].firstName == this.users[i].lastName) {
            return true;
        }
    }
})
```